# How to name coroutine in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

As per [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#naming-coroutines-for-debugging), we can name coroutine using `CoroutineName("theName")`

If I run it without the name (in the unit-test)

```
        runBlocking {
            launch { 
                println("main runBlocking pre       : ${Thread.currentThread().name}:${coroutineContext[Job]}")
                delay(500)
                println("main runBlocking post      : ${Thread.currentThread().name}:${coroutineContext[Job]}")
            }
```

Both the `Thread.currentThread().name` and `coroutineContext[Job]` will assign an ID to the coroutine name, hence the print out as below (notice `coroutine#2`)

```
main runBlocking pre       : main @coroutine#2:"coroutine#2":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@39529185
main runBlocking post      : main @coroutine#2:"coroutine#2":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@39529185
```

If I run it with the name (in the unit-test)

```
        runBlocking {
            launch(CoroutineName("CustomName")) { 
                println("main runBlocking pre       : ${Thread.currentThread().name}:${coroutineContext[Job]}")
                delay(500)
                println("main runBlocking post      : ${Thread.currentThread().name}:${coroutineContext[Job]}")
            }
```

It will print (notice the `@CustomName#2`)

```
main runBlocking pre       : main @CustomName#2:"CustomName#2":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@78e117e3
main runBlocking post      : main @CustomName#2:"CustomName#2":StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@78e117e3
```

However, if I run it in Android as below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        runBlocking {
            launch(CoroutineName("CustomName")) { // context of the parent, main runBlocking coroutine
                Log.d("Track", "main runBlocking pre       : ${Thread.currentThread().name}:${coroutineContext[Job]}")
                delay(500)
                Log.d("Track", "main runBlocking post      : ${Thread.currentThread().name}:${coroutineContext[Job]}")
            }
        }
    }
```

It prints

```
Track: main runBlocking pre       : main:StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@5e322c2
Track: main runBlocking post      : main:StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@5e322c2
```

The coroutine name is not given, nor is the coroutine assigned ID. I can only identify from the address ID i.e. `@5e322c2`, which is not guaranteed to be the same always.

How can I assign the coroutine name in Android?

Comment: Why are you accessing `coroutineContext[Job]` if you want the `CoroutineName` element? Have you tried `println(coroutineContext[CoroutineName]?.name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coroutine name is only used in debugging mode. However, you can enable in your application:

```
System.setProperty("kotlinx.coroutines.debug", "on" )
```

Comment: Works like a charm ;] I addes it to Application class